How can I improve the RMSE in my car price estimate?
How can I improve the RMSE in my car price estimate?

First, I will fill in the missing condition values ​​by estimating it based on the number of kilometers driven.

`
new_condition_df = df[df['condition'].map(condition_mapping) == 2]
top_1000_highest_mileage = new_condition_df.nlargest(1000, 'mileage')['mileage']
average_top_1000_highest_mileage = top_1000_highest_mileage.mean()

# Filter the DataFrame for rows where condition is null or unspecified
null_condition_df = df[df['condition'].isnull() | (df['condition'] == '')]

# Update 'condition' based on mileage condition
null_condition_df.loc[null_condition_df['mileage'] >= average_top_1000_highest_mileage, 'condition'] = 'CONDITION_USED'
null_condition_df.loc[null_condition_df['mileage'] < average_top_1000_highest_mileage, 'condition'] = 'CONDITION_NEW'

# Update the original DataFrame with the modified rows
df.update(null_condition_df)
`


Deleting a few empty lines

columns_with_null = ['color', 'vat_reclaimable', 'cubic_capacity', 'seller_country', 'feature']
df.dropna(subset=columns_with_null, inplace=True)

df['air_conditioning'].fillna('AIRCONDITIONING_NONE', inplace=True)
df['parking_camera'].fillna('PARKINGCAMERA_NONE', inplace=True)
df['parking_sensors'].fillna('PARKINGSENZOR_NONE', inplace=True)


Here I am trying to estimate the missing values ​​for the drive column, which contains information about whether the car is 4x4 or 4x2, drive contains a large number of null values, that is why I estimate it in such a complicated way

features = ['mileage', 'cubic_capacity', 'power', 'year'] + list(df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('car_style_')]) + list(df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('transmission_')]) + list(df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('fuel_type_')])

train_data = df.dropna(subset=['drive'])  # Odstranění řádků s chybějícími hodnotami sloupce 'drive'
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data[features], pd.get_dummies(train_data['drive']), test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

missing_data = df[df['drive'].isnull()]
X_missing = missing_data[features]
predicted_values = model.predict(X_missing)


df_imputed = df.copy()
predicted_df = pd.DataFrame(predicted_values, columns=y_train.columns, index=missing_data.index)
df_imputed.loc[df_imputed['drive'].isnull(), y_train.columns] = predicted_df.values

predicted_df_encoded = pd.DataFrame(predicted_values, columns=y_train.columns, index=missing_data.index)
predicted_df_encoded = (predicted_df_encoded > 0.5).astype(int)

for column in predicted_df_encoded.columns:
    df_imputed[column] = 0  # Přidání sloupce se všemi hodnotami 0
    df_imputed.loc[predicted_df_encoded.index, column] = predicted_df_encoded[column].values  

unique_values_imputed_encoded = df_imputed['drive'].unique()
df = df_imputed
df.drop(columns=['drive'], inplace=True)


Here I encode the feature field

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['feature']),columns=mlb.classes_))
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

df = df.drop(columns=['feature'])


The training itself

df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_encoded.drop(columns=['price_with_vat_czk']), df_encoded['price_with_vat_czk'], test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)


All program: https://onecompiler.com/python/42brp9a4r
Dataset https://filetransfer.io/data-package/a0mFEfg4#link
My RMSE is something about 64k

Any answer will be short, there is a lot of things to do and that's what I think the role of one data scientist is about. Some questions that you can do to yourself to start:

How bad is the RMSE in your model? how much do you think is better for you? what is your point of comparison to choose that metric and no other one?

I think there are some exploratory data analysis on the data that is missing, for instance you may see that your scatter plot is telling you that may be the linear regression is not the best approach. I have just tried myself with sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor with the by default hyperparameters, and the behavior of the resulting plot is better and the RMSE has decreased to around 45K, and R2 has moved from 0.88 to 0.94 (see sklearn.metrics.r2_score)
You can, for instance, get the correlation between your vector of features versus your target to see what is happening with the variables before to executing any model and you will see that is a high correlation with "year":
df_encoded.corr(method="spearman")["price_with_vat_czk"].sort_values()

You can try exploratory data analysis to tune better your features (statistics is your friend), also, you can try several algorithms, and after that, you can play with different hyperparameters (see sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV), then put your models in pipelines and try to get feature importance to reduce the dimensionality on the amount of features you have (see SHAP or GINI to do that)... To sum up, still a lot of things to do...

The idea itself is looking pretty good, but now you need to iterate over what you did, it's the funny part :).
Some things you could try out:

Improve preprocessing:
In general, I would try to understand better the data, plot it, analyse the distributions, see the correlation. Data is friend not food.
You could try normalizing the data (depending on the model you are going to use it matters a lot, a little or nothing).
Try removing outliers if you have too many of them.
If the distributions are skewed (like a normal distribution but "moved" you could try applying a logarithmic transformation

Try out different models:
Here you can try out a lot of stuff. I would recommend starting with a tree-based model, in my personal experience XGboost usually gives really good results, but I invite you to try different variations and research different methods!
If you really want to get a score you could even make your own assembly of models. That is, training for example 5 different models, each with it's strengths and weaknesses, and average (or something) the result of them all. But for this you first need 5 good models and think if combining them will improve or just decrease the RMSE of the best model.


Then you can try all of the boring stuff: use a grid search to change hyperparameters like the learning rate, the regulations terms, and all that stuff, but if you are trying to learn I would say that is secondary.
